# Flutter problem with display searching form firebase. Too many positional arguments

Tags: javascript, firebase, flutter, dart

Hello I have a problem with my code.
I want to display a list of a users from firebase, but im stuck at the end.
the line of code shuld look like this:

```
userName: searchSnapshopt.documents[index].data["name"]);
```

but after the update, there are no documents anymore and there is "docs" and it breaks everything down for me

here is my code

```html
class _SearchScrState extends State<SearchScr> {
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  TextEditingController searchTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();

  QuerySnapshot searchSnapshopt;

  initiateSearch() {
    databaseMethods
        .getUserByUsername(searchTextEditingController.text)
        .then((val) {
      setState(() {
        searchSnapshopt = val;
      });
    });
  }

  Widget searchList() {
    return searchSnapshopt != null
        ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: searchSnapshopt.docChanges.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SearchTile(
                  userName: searchSnapshopt.docs[0].data("name"));
            })
        : Container();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i have a solution, just change this

```
userName: searchSnapshopt.docs[index].data("name")
```

to this:

```
userName: searchSnapshopt.docs[index].get("name")
```

and now works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class _SearchScrState extends State<SearchScr> {
  DatabaseMethods databaseMethods = new DatabaseMethods();
  TextEditingController searchTextEditingController =
      new TextEditingController();

  QuerySnapshot searchSnapshopt;

  initiateSearch() {
    databaseMethods
        .getUserByUsername(searchTextEditingController.text)
        .then((val) {
      setState(() {
        searchSnapshopt = val;
      });
    });
  }

  Widget searchList() {
    return searchSnapshopt != null
        ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: searchSnapshopt.docChanges.length,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return SearchTile(
                  userName: searchSnapshopt.docs[index].get("name"));
            })
        : Container();
  }
```